# mhchem macro in subscript

Tags: macros, mhchem

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  %   c_\ce{CO2} not working
  c_{\ce{CO2}} \quad c_\text{working}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

which produce

[image]

Now: why do I have to embrace (all the puns intended) the `\ce{CO2}` macro with braces, while the `\text{}` macro doesn't need them? The commented text produces an error `missing { inserted c_\ce{CO2}`

Comment: The fact that `\text` works without the braces is purely incidental and should not be relied upon. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160538/4427

Comment: To explain what happens, the expansion of `\text` starts with `{`, which is then used for the subscript.

Comment: In the same way as `\mathrm{}`, as you explain in the question above?

Comment: Not completely the same, but basically so. I think I have already explained the behavior somewhere, and I'm trying to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what `amstext.sty` says:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\text}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text@\else\expandafter\mbox\fi}
\def\text@#1{{\mathchoice
  {\textdef@\displaystyle\f@size{#1}}%
  {\textdef@\textstyle\f@size{\firstchoice@false #1}}%
  {\textdef@\textstyle\sf@size{\firstchoice@false #1}}%
  {\textdef@\textstyle \ssf@size{\firstchoice@false #1}}%
  \check@mathfonts
  }%
}
```

If we are in math mode, when `\text{xyz}` is found, TeX follows the “true” branch and so is presented with `\text@{xyz}` (because the `\else...\fi` is discarded.

Then it substitutes `\text@` with its definition, that is,

```
{\mathchoice{...}}
```

and these additional braces keep `_` happy. We must recall that `_` in math mode causes expansion of the following tokens.

I guess that the additional braces were introduced just for avoiding unscrutable errors that `_\text{xyz}` would produce otherwise.

Unfortunately, it *allows* that kind of “wrong” input. It's much similar to what happens with `_\mathrm{xyz}`, that I have roughly explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160538/4427

On the other hand, the definition of `\ce` has nothing of this kind:

```
\newcommand*{\ce}{%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \csname ce \expandafter\endcsname
  \else
    \ifx\protect\@unexpandable@protect
      \protect@unexpand@cmd@arg\ce
    \else
      \ifx\protect\string
        \protect@string@cmd@arg\ce
      \else
        \expandafter\protect@unknown@cmd@arg
        \csname ce \endcsname
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

This will definitely make TeX unhappy upon seeing `_\ce{...}`.

Comment: I think this might be related to [my problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642887/213149). I would be really grateful if you could take a look.