# How to put chemical formula into subscript with mhchem

Tags: mhchem

I would like to put chemical formulas into subscripts/superscripts. For example, `$M_\ce{H}$` should denote mass of H atom. However, this fails in recent version of `mhchem` (4.02)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    M_\ce{H}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Saying

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_let:D 
l.6     M_\ce{H}

? q
```

I know that it used to work in previous version of `mhchem` (3.07), but adding `\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}` doesn't help. Is there some other way how to do it?

Comment: This wasn't true for all versions 3 of `mhchem`. If this ever worked I guess it was by chance http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239301/mhchem-macro-in-subscript

Comment: @clemens A dupe of the older question perhaps?

Comment: @Joseph maybe. Although the error is different both cause and solution are the same...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sub- and superscripts should be given in braces if they are not a single token. Whilst some cases do work without this (for example `$M_\mathrm{n}$`) this is not generally true. Here, the document will work correctly with eh official LaTeX syntax

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    M_{\ce{H}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```