# Define macro for \Big, \bigg etc

Tags: macros, delimiters

Is it possible to make macro behave as if it was written directly?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\veca}{|_{\vec{a}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\bigg\veca \qquad \frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\bigg|_{\vec{a}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: better to use a syntax such as `\newcommand{\veca}[1][]{#1|_{\vec{a}}`  then `\veca[\bigg]` when you want a size (see the paired delimiter commands in `mahtools`

Comment: `\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\expandafter\bigg\veca` works out, so I suppose `\bigg` triggers some lookahead at the next token not taking into account that that could be expandable.

Comment: @UlrichDiez It's not that it doesn't take expandable commands into account, it's that it's quite common to pass macros there which should not be expanded beforehand. (e.g. `\expandafter\bigg\vert` would break)

Comment: I understand that you want the size of the vertical bar to automatically adjust to what precedes. You could simply write `\left.\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\right\veca`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default definition of `\Big` and friends sets the delimiter as a left delimiter, so having a subscript on it ends up being the first element in the delimited list and therefore does not get placed relative to the delimiter. This can be avoided by defining `\Big` and friends in the opposite way: Make the delimiter a right delimiter, such that the subscript becomes a subscript of the whole delimited list.

While this fixes the placement, it can have side effects on how the subscript is placed (mostly `\nulldelimiterskip` is zero and the style is always scriptstyle) but for most usecases this shouldn't matter.

Given that `amsmath` defines `\big` based on `\bBigg@` it's enough to change the definition of that macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand \bBigg@[2]{%
  {\@mathmeasure\z@{\nulldelimiterspace\z@}%
     {\left.\vcenter to#1\big@size{}\right#2}%
   \box\z@}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\veca}{|_{\vec{a}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\bigg\veca \qquad \frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\bigg|_{\vec{a}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's so clever. Thank you so much! I wish you had posted this before I spent lots of time doing it with `expl3`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of @DavidCarlisle's suggestion to make `veca` take an optional argument, the difference being that I suggest setting `\biggr` as the default value of the optional argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\providecommand{\veca}[1][\biggr]{#1\vert_{\vec{a}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\veca
\quad
\frac{u(\vec{x})}{v(\vec{x})}\veca[\Bigr]
\quad
h(\vec{z})\veca[]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't start a bounty if this solution satisfied me.

Comment: @antshar - You're certainly entirely free, and welcome, to edit your posting and clarifty what exactly your typesetting objective is.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but such constructions work out of the box in ConTeXt LMTX (i.e., with the luametatex engine).

```
\define\veca{\rvert_{\vec{a}}}

\starttext
\startformula
\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\Bigg\veca \qquad \frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\Bigg|_{\vec{a}}
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

I am not sure what is different beneath the hood for this to work correctly.

Note that the size of `\bigg` and `\Bigg` are different because ConTeXt does scaling of delimiters a bit differently, and the placement of the subscript is different (that is because luatex engine reads the spacing values from the font; you get similar spacing in lualatex as well).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make macro behave as if it was written directly?

Since TeX evaluate "left-to-right", if you have `\outermacro{\innermacro}` and keep `outermacro` intact <sup>(*1)</sup>, nothing can force it to expand `innermacro` if it doesn't want to.

<sup>(*1)</sup>: the OP's [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/643498/250119) address the case of modifying the outer macro. Works as well.

Unless... `\veca` is not-quite a macro. Do this to do replacement on the source code before reading each line.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
    function translate(line)
        line=string.gsub(line, [[\veca([^A-Za-z])]], [[|_{\vec{a}}%1]])
        line=string.gsub(line, [[\veca$]], [[|_{\vec{a}}]])
        return line
    end
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", translate, "veca special replacement")
```

```
\end{luacode*}


\begin{document}

\[
\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\bigg\veca \qquad \frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\bigg|_{\vec{a}}
\]


% test:
\def\vecab{\vec{ab}}
\[
\vecab
% ^^ middle of a word, don't replace
+
x\veca
% ^^ end of line, still replace
\]

\end{document}
```

Of course, this way it doesn't behave the same way a macro does, e.g. if it appear in `\verb` it will still be replaced with the result. And it's up to you to write the "parser" correctly.

Comment: I'm not responsible if you forget about this replacement thing and wonder why you get mysterious errors when the code totally looks correctly.

Comment: Side note, things other than LuaTeX can do this replacement too, but there are some... *drawbacks*.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expl3}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:NN \better_big:nn \bBigg@

\cs_set:Npn \bBigg@ #1#2 {
  \tl_set:Nx \arg_rest_tokens { \tl_tail:N {#2} }
  \tl_set:Nx \arg_first_token { \tl_head:N {#2} }
  \tl_set:Nx \arg_first_token_exp { \tl_head:f {#2} }
  \exp_last_unbraced:No \token_if_eq_meaning:NNT \arg_first_token \delimiter {
    \use_none_delimit_by_q_nil:w
  }
  \exp_last_unbraced:No \token_if_eq_meaning:NNF \arg_first_token_exp \delimiter {
    \exp_last_unbraced:Nno \str_if_in:nnF {\{\}} {\arg_first_token} {
      \int_compare:nF { \exp_last_unbraced:NNV \delcode`\arg_first_token > 0 } {
        \use_none_delimit_by_q_nil:w
      }
    }
  }
  \better_big:nn {#1} {\arg_first_token} \arg_rest_tokens
  \use_none_delimit_by_q_stop:w
  \use_none_delimit_by_q_nil:w \q_nil
  \better_big:nn {#1}{#2}
  \use_none_delimit_by_q_stop:w \q_stop
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\newcommand{\veca}{|_{\vec{a}}}
\newcommand{\ketb}{\rangle^*}
\newcommand{\lnorm}{\|}
\newcommand{\rnorm}{\|_\infty}


\begin{document}

Custom macros next to \verb|\Big, \bigg|, etc
\[
\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\bigg\veca \qquad
\big\lnorm A\vec{x} \big\rnorm \qquad
\Big|\Phi(t)\Big\ketb
\]

Doesn't break the regular behaviour
\[
\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\bigg|_{\vec{a}} \qquad
\big\| A\vec{x} \big\|_\infty \qquad
\Big|\Phi(t)\Big\rangle^*
\]

\end{document}
```

---

The question itself seems pretty simple, doesn't it. However, it appeared way harder to achieve that I firstly though, to be honest.

It took me lots of effort to finally solve the problem. I have to thank everyone who contributed to this and helped me to solve adjacent questions.

Special thanks to [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) that come up with the way to [detect delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/643507/213149) in general.

---

#### Explanation

All `\big`, `\bigg`, `\Big`, `\Bigg` are defined in [`amsmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) like so

```
\renewcommand{\big}{\bBigg@\@ne}
\renewcommand{\Big}{\bBigg@{1.5}}
\renewcommand{\bigg}{\bBigg@\tw@}
\renewcommand{\Bigg}{\bBigg@{2.5}}
\ifx\leavevmode@ifvmode\@undefined
\def\bBigg@#1#2{%
  {\@mathmeasure\z@{\nulldelimiterspace\z@}%
     {\left#2\vcenter to#1\big@size{}\right.}%
   \box\z@}}
\else
\def\bBigg@#1#2{\leavevmode@ifvmode
  {\@mathmeasure\z@{\nulldelimiterspace\z@}%
     {\left#2\vcenter to#1\big@size{}\right.}%
   \box\z@}}
\fi
```

so the changes need to apply only to `\bBigg@`

First what comes to mind is to simply expand the argument of `\big`s commands. It works at the first sight, but actually it breaks some of cases, for example `\big\vert` would led to an error.

Therefore, the idea that eventually implemented is the following:
Check whether the argument is expandable and if so, check the first argument of the expansion, i.e `\veca`'s expansion is `{|_\vec{a}}` and then I check the first token of that list and if it's a delimiter then I pass only it to the `\big` command and everything else just appends rightwards.