# Expand argument before using it

Tags: expl3, expansion, latex3

This question is my attempt to solve the [main problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642887/213149) (MWE there).

I realized that using macro

```
\newcommand{\veca}{|_{\vec{a}}}
```

next to `\bigg` is being treated as a single token, so those two queries have the same output

```
\bigg\veca
\bigg{|_{\vec{a}}}
```

[image]

I don't know how to define `\veca` the way it's being expanded first, so my attempt was to redefine `\bigg` so that the second argument always expands once

I looked up in `amsmath.sty` and figured out that all `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, `\Bigg` are defined using `\bBigg@`:

```
\renewcommand{\big}{\bBigg@\@ne}
\renewcommand{\Big}{\bBigg@{1.5}}
\renewcommand{\bigg}{\bBigg@\tw@}
\renewcommand{\Bigg}{\bBigg@{2.5}}
\ifx\leavevmode@ifvmode\@undefined
\def\bBigg@#1#2{%
  {\@mathmeasure\z@{\nulldelimiterspace\z@}%
     {\left#2\vcenter to#1\big@size{}\right.}%
   \box\z@}}
\else
\def\bBigg@#1#2{\leavevmode@ifvmode
  {\@mathmeasure\z@{\nulldelimiterspace\z@}%
     {\left#2\vcenter to#1\big@size{}\right.}%
   \box\z@}}
\fi
```

And here's my attempt to implement the expansion using [`expl3`](https://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\veca}{|_{\vec{a}}}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:NN \better_big:nn \bBigg@
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \better_big:nn {no}

\cs_set:Npn \bBigg@ #1#2 {
    \better_big:no #1 #2
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\bigg\veca \qquad
\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\bigg|_{\vec{a}}
\]

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't seem to work at all
[image]

---

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Pure LaTeX2 solutions are really welcome as well.

Comment: Why not just use `\veca[\bigg] {...} ` and define it to take an optional arg

Comment: @daleif it's not intuitive and not versatile. `\veca` is only one of many similar macros that I'm going to create. Using sequence `\bigg<someting>` allows to make hot-replacement of delimiters. I'd rather make effort to make it work as expected than use the easiest "solution" that doesn't require savvy.

Comment: Well, the long-time members know exactly what is "easy" and what is "hard" to achieve in TeX... and kind of just fixate on the things that can be done easily/efficiently (possibly at the cost of somewhat-complex input format). Knuth TeX is more on the "minimal markup" side at the cost of complexity (see e.g. \over macro in plain TeX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. But o-type expansion braces the result by default, so you need one that does not brace.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\veca}{|_{\vec{a}}}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:NN \better_big:nn \bBigg@

\cs_set:Npn \bBigg@ #1#2 {
    \exp_last_unbraced:Nno \better_big:nn {#1} {#2}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\bigg\veca \qquad
\frac{f(\vec{x})}{g(\vec{x})}\bigg|_{\vec{a}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that the o-expansion of `#2` must be brace-balanced.

---

Note that this will break some other usages e.g. see the comment. One way I can see to fix the issue is to test if the inner macro is one that "wants to be expanded" e.g.

```
\cs_set:Npn \bBigg@ #1#2 {
    \tl_if_eq:nnTF {#2} {\veca} {
        \exp_last_unbraced:Nno \better_big:nn {#1} {#2}
    }
    {
        \better_big:nn {#1} {#2}
    }
}
```

(look, TeX is not magic. Then if you want some system to mark whether a macro as "want to be expanded or not" you can define some auxiliary macro etc. it gets complex quickly. `functional` package does something similar to see if an inner macro in the argument "is a function")

Comment: This will also force a level of brace to `#1` (so it may be `{\@ne}` or `{1.5}`), but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you. I'm accepting this answer, because it answers the exact questing, however the expansion seem to lead to the problem with other delimiters like `\rangle` that now cause an error if next to `\bigg`.

Comment: (side note, `\rangle` expands to something that is longer than one token, so of course the change will modify its behavior → an error)

Comment: Thanks, but it's more like a brute force. As I mentioned in comments to the post, eventually I'll have lots of `\veca`-like commands, so I'll have to manually adjust the condition for `\better_big` for each new command. You fully answered this concrete question, so now I'm going to try out another approach (not direct expansion): parse the second argument and if it starts with a delimiter (`|`, `)`, etc.) then expand, in other cases don't expand. If I don't manage to do this myself, I'll create a new post.

Comment: @antshar Not really. As I mentioned in the answer you can e.g. define a macro `\veca__wants_to_be_expanded`, then when `#2` is a single macro `\x` checks if `\x__wants_to_be_expanded` is defined -- which is what `functional` package does.